# Meteor SEO when Template-level subscriptions

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, seo, subscriptions

I've wrote a web-app using Meteor and I encounter difficulties with SEO.

I'm using a fork of Spiderable (jazeee-meteor-spiderable) for Meteor and I'm having some trouble setting `Meteor.isReadyForSpiderable = true;` when subscriptions are defined in the template and not the route.

Paginated tables are good example of this case.

I tried to wait `Template.subscriptionReady()` in the `Template.templateName.onCreated` callback, but there's nothing concluent.

Any idea for handling that kind of data loading ?

Here's my code:

```js
Template.list.onCreated(function () {
    this.autorun(() => {
        if (this.subscriptionReady()) {
            Meteor.isReadyForSpiderable = true;
            console.log('ready');
        } else {
            Meteor.isReadyForSpiderable = false;
            console.log('not ready yet');
        }

        console.log(Meteor.isReadyForSpiderable);
    });
});
```

Thanks,